# Exit while loop when button is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a Python/Raspberry Pi game with some LEDS and one switch. I'm trying to exit a loop when a button is pressed and see which LED stays open, the problem is that the way I'm doing it right now doesn't work. Any ideas on how to exit the loop when there's the input from the button.

EDIT: I want to be able to exit the loop while the script is sleeping.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
def check():
    input_state = GPIO.input(26)
    if input_state == False:
        break
while True:
    GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
    check()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    check()
    GPIO.output(6,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
    check()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    check()
    GPIO.output(19,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(13,GPIO.HIGH)
    check()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    check()
    GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic backwards; when you *do* get a keypress 26, you want to exit.  Also, the `break` *must* be *inside* the loop: yours is off in a function, where all you can "break" is the function.  Instead ...

```
def check():
    input_state = GPIO.input(26)
    return input_state

while True:
    GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
    if check():
        break
...
```

Comment: Thanks. And there's any way to avoid having to put the 'if' statement every time the LED is on or off?

Comment: No, because you *do* have that many branches in your foundation logic.  You *could* parameterize each section of output-check-if-break, but that might be uglier than you want.